# accessing request header in angular

Tags: angularjs, nginx, http-headers

I have a setup where via the nginx config file traffic on port 8000 is routed to an index.html page that then invokes some Angular code that processes the request. I am new to Angular so I don't really know how the request makes it to this code but it does. The code looks like this, and control is passed to the `init = function()`:

```
module.exports = function($scope, $routeParams, $sce, $timeout, $http, config) {
    $scope.config = config;
    $scope.identifiers = [];

    var init = function(){ ... }
```

In that function I want to get the request headers. Is there a way to do that?

Edit in attempt to clarify:

I know it's screwy, but I didn't write this, it was just dropped in my lap. When a request is sent on port 8000 the angular code runs. I know it's client side, but that's what happens. I need to check the auth of the initial request. If I cannot do that in the client can I do at the nginx level somehow?

Comment: Angular code runs in the client, so does it make sense to get request header in the init function of controller?

Comment: I don't know, I'm new to this. Let me tell you want I want to do - I need to determine the behavour of the angular code based on the request - specifically, if the user is authorized. The request can come from different sources, some under my control, and some not under my control. In the ones under my control I want to set a header indicating that the request can be serviced, if an authorized user is making the request. If that header field is not present and the proper value then the request cannot be serviced. If using a header field is not the proper way to do this, what is?

Comment: Easiest is for your authorized source to pass a query parameter in the url such as http://example.org?authorized=1 that calls your angular code and check for that using something such as the $location.search method - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: But then anyone could send that from a browser and get access. I wanted something more hidden, hence I was thinking of a header field.

Comment: @LarryMartell: If session ID is set in cookie you can check if user is authorized by checking the cookie. You can use $cookies for that

Comment: Probably looking at this wrong ... if it can't be serviced return an unauthorized status which would then go into catch of request promise.

Comment: @ArunGhosh That might be a good idea - but the requests can come from either a C++ Qt app or a django app, so I have to see how to set a cookie in both of those cases. Probably not hard.

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, but the question is, how can I tell if I should service the request or not?

Comment: cookie or custom **request** header. After reviewing comments more and seeing requests might come from another server... header would seem more appropriate

Comment: @charlietfl Well that brings me back to my original question - how do I access the request header in the angular code?

Comment: You want to set not get header. Is outlined in `$http` docs. Can set globally using a `$httpinterceptor` or set on per request basis

Comment: As for the httpinterceptor...there are numerous tutorials around as well as the docs

Comment: @charlietfl don't understand 'set not get'. The header field will be set in the requester (C++ or django, which is easy), and I need to get and test it in the Angular code. That is what I don't know how to do.

Comment: No...that would be backwards...you are wanting to send some sort of validation token to server and use that to determine if request should be serviced or not. If yes..return data...if no return unauthorized status

Comment: Although conversely the token would first need to come from server as header or as response body so I guess I see it both ways. In angular headers are part of `$http` response object

Comment: @charlietfl The server being nginx? So are you saying I have to do that validation there? How would I do that?

Comment: Not sure what your authorization strategy is. Most would use token based auth to be able to work with both client and other servers

Comment: I don't have a strategy, I'm trying to figure out what to do. As I said earlier up in the comments, the request can come from different sources, some under my control, and some not under my control. In the ones under my control I want to indicate in some way to the code that services the request, which is written in Angular, that the request should be serviced. If you can tell me the best way to do this, that would be great.

Comment: Suggest starting with a server side strategy. Something like JWT or Oauth. Not my specialty determining best solution...am better at feeding end point from client. then when you have that sorted out worry about headers/cookies

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113223/discussion-between-charlietfl-and-larry-martell).